# How do I correctly use mock call_args with Python's unittest.mock?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mocking, python-mock

Consider the following files:

**holy_hand_grenade.py**

```
def count(one, two, five='three'):
    print('boom')
```

**test_holy_hand_grenade.py**

```
from unittest import mock
import holy_hand_grenade

def test_hand_grenade():
    mock_count = mock.patch("holy_hand_grenade.count", autospec=True)
    with mock_count as fake_count:
        fake_count(1, 2, five=5)

        # According to https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.call_args
        # this should work
        assert fake_count.call_args.kwargs['five'] == 5
```

According to the docs, `call_args` should be:

> This is either None (if the mock hasn’t been called), or the arguments that the mock was last called with. This will be in the form of a tuple: the first member, which can also be accessed through the args property, is any ordered arguments the mock was called with (or an empty tuple) and the second member, **which can also be accessed through the kwargs property, is any keyword arguments (or an empty dictionary).**

(emphasis mine)

But this blows up in my face, with `TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str`

Um. No?

The thing I really don't understand, is that if this is a call object, which it is, because

```
assert isinstance(fake_count.call_args, (mock._Call,))
```

passes, it's supposed to have kwargs and args. And it... well, it sort of does. But they appear to not actually be the correct thing:

```
assert isinstance(fake_count.call_args.kwargs, (mock._Call,))  #this works
assert isinstance(fake_count.call_args.kwargs, (dict,))  # doesn't work
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Fun fact (although possibly related), `isinstance(fake_count.call_args.blablabla, (mock._Call,))` is `True` as well (and indeed this applies to any attribute one might attempt to access)

Comment: So I discovered :P I *can* access the element via the tuple-ish access, but... the docs *say* there's args and kwargs, dang it!

Comment: All you are doing is calling a `Mock` object. The fact that it patches anything is irrelevant, both because you aren't using the patched name, and because you are calling something that is known to just be a `Mock`. Perhaps you want to use `wraps`, so that calling `count` will both call the original object *and* collect information about the call that you can query.

Comment: Upvoted simply because of the chuckle factor (#montypython)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a feature introduced in Python 3.8 in [this issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue21269).

The [3.7 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.call_args) does not mention it (while the [newest docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.call_args) do) - so you have to access the arguments by index in Python < 3.8.

Comment: Confirmed that this works on Python 3.8 - Nice catch!