# How to check arguments passed to a method of a mocked object

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I am trying to use `unittest.mock.MagicMock` to mock an API.  I am not understanding to how check the arguments passed to a method on a mocked object.  I thought that this should work:

```py
from unittest import mock

import unittest

class TestMock(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        pass

    def test_basic(self):
        obj = unittest.mock.MagicMock()
        obj.update(1,2,a=3)

        print("obj.update: ", obj.update)
        print("obj.update.call_args: ", obj.update.call_args)
        print("obj.update.call_args.args: ", obj.update.call_args.args)

        self.assertEqual((1,2), obj.update.call_args.args)
```

However, `pytest test_mock.py` fails:

```
test_mock.py:17: AssertionError
------------------------------------------------ Captured stdout call ------------------------------------------------
obj.update:  <MagicMock name='mock.update' id='140707024533072'>
obj.update.call_args:  call(1, 2, a=3)
obj.update.call_args.args:  args
============================================== short test summary info ===============================================
FAILED test_mock.py::TestMock::test_basic - AssertionError: (1, 2) != args
================================================= 1 failed in 0.10s ==================================================
```

[The docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.call_args) say that I should be able to access the positional args via the `call_args.args`, but that seems to be creating a mocked field instead.  What is the correct way to verify the arguments?

Comment: I can't reproduce this.  Ran your exact code in the REPL and `obj.update.call_args.args` is `(1, 2)`.  What is this `args` object that you've got?  It's not a mock object, and I don't think it's a string either.  I'd be very curious what `type(obj.update.call_args.args)` shows.

Comment: `type(obj.update.call_args.args):  <class 'unittest.mock._Call'>`. I figured out the problem.  `args` and `kwargs` were added in 3.8 and this project is using 3.7.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I correctly use mock call\_args with Python's unittest.mock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60105443/how-do-i-correctly-use-mock-call-args-with-pythons-unittest-mock). Ah - I see you already found it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `args` and `kwargs` values were introduce in Python 3.8.  This behavior is seen when using Python 3.7 or earlier.